# What is the new point reflected with a respect to fixed line through origin?

Tags: analytic-geometry

If I have $ P(x,y)$, what would be the reflected point with respect to fixed line through origin O?

Does it depend on what line I have, If I have $x$ or $2x$ $3x$, they all pass through origin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(p,q)$ be the point you have and let $y=ax\ (a\not=0)$ be the line we consider.

Then, let $Q(X,Y)$ be the point you want.

First, since the midpoint of the line segment $PQ$ is on the line $y=ax$, we have
$$\frac{q+Y}{2}=a\cdot \frac{p+X}{2}.$$
Second, since the line $PQ$ is perpendicular to the line $y=ax$, we have
$$-\frac 1a=\frac{Y-q}{X-p}.$$
Solving these gives you 
$$X=\frac{2aq+(1-a^2)p}{a^2+1},\ \ \ Y=\frac{2ap+(a^2-1)q}{a^2+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if the questions says "fixed" does that mean that there is only one line?

Comment: @aaa: "fixed" means that we consider a fixed line such as $y=2x,y=3x,y=4x$ (it implies that the line does not move at all). There are infinitely many lines which pass through the origin. In other words, the letter $a$ in my answer is a constant. You can put any real number in $a$.